# How to play a sound file from a web URL when a button is clicked

Tags: android, button, media-player

I have this sound file in `http://www.example.com/sound.mp3`; how can I make it play when a button is clicked, using a Media Player?

Example:

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mmmm); }

     });
```

But I want to play this sound: `http://www.example.com/sound.mp3` without downloading this sound.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if a question fixed your problem